# update statement using php mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a table with the below values:

```
Table
-----------------------------------------------------------
Column               | Type           | Default
-----------------------------------------------------------
name                   varchar(100)     none
loginCount             int(11)          0
lastLoginDate          datetime         0000-00-00 00:00:00
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I want to check if the user is logged in properly and if yes, update `loginCount` and `lastLoginDate` correspondingly.

The `php` script is as below:

```
<?php
  // Verification query..
  if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $sql = "UPDATE table
               SET `loginCount` = `loginCount` + 1,
                   `lastLoginDate` = now()
             WHERE `name` = '".$username"'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
  }
?>
```

**The issue is, this is NOT working!**

However, if I use the same by logging into `mysql` console directly, the update happens!

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: check your mysql.log file if the query is being fired and if it does what are the parameters it is sending.

Comment: Is your table really called `table`? If so, that's a reserved keyword and you need to quote it with backticks, just as you have your columns.

Comment: Also, `if (!$result) echo mysql_error();`

Comment: you might also check the value of `$username`, it might not be what you expect.

Comment: And of course, `echo $sql` to see the query that is going to be executed.

Comment: and please stop using the `mysql` extension for php, rather start using `mysqli`, it is almost the same and you won't find it difficult to switch. `mysql` is soon going to be deprecated and php will most probably not bundle it in the next release.

Comment: @Micheal, I did all that. Checked `$username`, `$sql`. But `$result` shows Fail. What might be the reason?

Comment: @curlyreggie If `$result === FALSE`, then you must check `echo mysql_error();`. Also, you have already used `$result` as the resource for your first query. Even though you have done only one fetch call and it shouldn't collide, I recommend using a different variable for the second `mysql_query()` call to cause less confusion.

Comment: I don't know why but this above suggestion worked!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `.` for concatenation before the closing quote

```
WHERE `name` = '".$username"'";
//------------------------^^^
```

Should be

```
WHERE `name` = '".$username . "'";
//--------------------------^^^
```

Or better, omit the concatenation because you are enclosing in double quotes.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET ..... WHERE `name` = '$username'";
```

This means you probably don't have error_reporting enabled, or you would see a syntax error.

Something like:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)...

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Finally, it should not cause problems, I wouldn't expect based on the posted code, but it is unwise to reuse `$result`, which is the result resource variable from your first (unseen here) query. You will not be able to fetch again from it later if needed, once it has been overwritten by `TRUE/FALSE` from the `UPDATE` statement. Use a different variable for the `UPDATE` success/failure.

```
$other_var_not_result_for_clarity = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: @curlyreggie Did you debug it by showing testing for true/false on `$result` and showing errors as suggested in the comments?  If no row is updated and there is no error (`$result` is true), then `$username` does not contain what you expect it to.

Comment: @curlyreggie And did you debug the first query from which you fetched `$row`? Did it return a row causing the fetch to enter the `if` block?